# A/V sync issue - Apple's HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ipad, http-live-streaming, m3u, audio-video-sync

When I try to stream TS chunks generated by 3rd party multiplexers (Mainconcept/Elecard) from Safari browser in IPad 2.0/1.0 I always see Audio Video synchronization issue over a period of time.

But the same clips are playing fine in standard media player in Windows PC or Macbook.

I also observe that there is no issue in IPad when I try to stream TS chunks generated by Media File Segmenter tool in MAcbook.

What is that IPad is expecting from 3rd party multiplexers?

For Ex: When I try to stream a set TS chunks in Ipad where the overall chunk duration is 5mts 35 secs (including all TS chunks), I observe audio goes out of sync after 2 mts 40 secs.

Following is the media pipeline used to generate TS chunks

Video.mp4 (Source)-> Mainconcept MPEG4 DeMultiplexer-> Mainconcept MPEG Multiplxer-> Mainconcept Sink Filter (Generates TS chunks based on time)

Can someone share some points on IPad HLS behaviour? Does IPad expects some additional parameters for synchronization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Mainconcept Multiplexer settings, enable "optimized packing". This will resolve the AV sync issue